# How do I supply Vidoes (.mp4) stored on google Storage to my Android app Mediaplayer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to 'google cloud' development. I am trying the following

- creating android app
- using 'cloud endpoints' to access 'NoSql datastore'
- uploaded bunch of videos to 'google cloud storage' thinking I can access these videos from my android app directly, something like
  `videoView.setVideoPath("https://storage.cloud.google.com/.../movie.mp4");`

My videos don't play and getting error 'can't play video'. I am kind of guessing some permission error or I am not accessing these videos from my android app properly.

If anyone of you can point me to documentation on how to set this app, I am looking for something explained in this picture

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-oqycQvdB5fQ/Un23SZQCBPI/AAAAAAAAAOA/k-MZl_05ta4/s1600/MBS+v3-2x+(1).png

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is more and Android related question.

Using video.setVideoPath will look for the video in the local storage. Instead you should do something like this:

```
videoView.setVideoUri(Uri.parse("https://storage.cloud.google.com/.../movie.mp4");
```

Comment: Nope didn't work, thank you. Video plays if I use some other site, but not from my cloud storage

Comment: @mahabudhi may be is a permission issue? is that file public? It it needs to be private and you are using cloud endpoints, may be you can access it from cloud endpoints and serve it though your api.

Comment: yes it's private, how can I serve it through 'cloud endpoints', can you point me to some documentation or example.

Comment: I would put that video file public for a moment and test that works as expected. If it works then serve it through cloud endpoints. Here you have a step by step codelab (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android) and general documentation for further information (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)

Comment: I did make this video 'public' and still it does not load (using `videoView.setVideoUri(Uri.parse("https://storage.cloud.google.com/.../movie.mp4");`),     What do you mean by serve it through cloud endpoints, do you mean pass the URI or is there a mechanism to pass the 'video stream' through cloud endpoints

Comment: I was able to play video (public one), the issue was URL, correct one is `https://storage.googleapis.com/my bucket name/movie.mp4`, not the previous

Comment: great, glad it worked. So, solution was use setVideoUri() with the correct URL, right?

Comment: even without `setVideoUri()` it works too, also this works only for public links, still need to figure out how to set permissions to my app so that I can access these private links too